# Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder enable field visibility ANY

Tags: java, spring, jackson, spring-boot

I'm using spring-boot and want to customize the ObjectMapper created.

What I want to do is be able to serialize objects that do not have a getter or setters. Before this could be done by putting JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY on the ObjectMapper.

But how can I enable this feature using the Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder bean I'm currently exposing ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` subclass that overrides the `configure(ObjectMapper)` method:

```java
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder() {
    return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder() {

        @Override
        public void configure(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
            super.configure(objectMapper);
            objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
        }

    };

}
```

Comment: app is failing to start with boot 1.4.0 and this `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at org.springframework.data.rest.core.UriToEntityConverter.<init>(UriToEntityConverter.java:71) ~[spring-data-rest-core-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:na]`

Comment: looking at the line before that... `PersistentEntity<?, ?> entity = entities.getPersistentEntity(rawType);` where `rawType` is `JsonDeserializer`...

Comment: it seems to only happen as a result of defining `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` as a subclass

Comment: This method will disable any `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` beans that are applied in the original `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` bean method (_JacksonAutoConfiguration.java_)

Answer (score 8):

If you want to keep the ObjectMapper configurable through the spring.jackson.* properties that Spring Boot provides, then you better don't define your own Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder bean (check JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration inside JacksonAutoConfiguration class for details).

What you can do instead is this:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder mapperBuilder) {
    return mapperBuilder.build().setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
}
```

Comment: I had to exclude HypermediaAutoConfiguration for this solution to work, see [SpringFox dependency breaking my Spring Context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31307883/springfox-dependency-breaking-my-spring-context/32281734#32281734)

Answer (score 1):

I spend a half of day to play with different settings.
So I manage to work it (1.3.2.RELEASE) when:

- I configure jackson in simple `@Configuration` annotated config class (not extended from `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`)
- I have NOT`@EnableWebMvc`

Then `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder` solution is
work, but `spring.jackson.serialization.indent_output: true` in properties ignored.

At last I finished with

```
 @Autowired(required = true)
 public void configeJackson(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
     objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
 }
```

But all this is puzzle for me. I wrote a question about any explanation of all this magic in order to have some undestanding and solve problem not by
trial-and-error method: [Are there any Spring Boot documentation for understanding how web mvc configuration is work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35327027/are-there-any-spring-boot-documentation-for-understanding-how-web-mvc-configurat)