# SpringFox dependency breaking my Spring Context

Tags: java, spring, swagger

Until recently I've been getting my swagger documentation mostly-free, because I was using Camel to expose my REST APIs. I've had to ditch Camel because of some problems it has playing nice with Jackson, so I'm trying to set up SpringFox. Unfortunately, simply adding SpringFox as a dependency wrecks my Spring context somehow, and throws a vague and incorrect error claiming I don't have an explicit ObjectMapper bean, which I do - the inability to make Camel use said bean is why I had to remove it.

To be clear, without making any code changes, just adding the following dependency:

```
compile group: "io.springfox", name: "springfox-swagger2" version: "2.0.2"
```

Causes the problem. I'm using Jackson 2.5.3 and Spring Boot 1.2.3.RELEASE

FWIW here's the interesting part of the stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hateoas.HypermediaAutoConfiguration$HypermediaConfiguration$HalObjectMapperConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hateoas.HypermediaAutoConfiguration$HypermediaConfiguration$HalObjectMapperConfiguration.primaryObjectMapper; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: objectMapper,_halObjectMapper
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:101)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86)
    ... 45 more
```

Comment: The error is pretty straight foward, there are either two classes or two beans or two implementations for the same component. `expected single matching bean but found 2: objectMapper,_halObjectMapper`. Maybe you are havving a conflict with the library you are using.

Comment: How do I find out which @Configuration class is exposing it, in order to exclude it from @EnableAutoConfiguration?

Comment: I would find out which jars has this class: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` then I would see which ones have dependency to it and then exclude it from one of then. You can do a test excluding the Jackson dependency from your springfox dependency

Comment: There is probably more of the stack trace either before it, less likely after it ... would you mind posting all the stack trace? that way you could walk the dependency chain and see which bean is causing the problem.it would be great to try and identify the issue and possibly fix this.  I'd recommend you create an issue in http://springfox.io  preferably with a repo that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I suspect you have an `@EnableHypermediaSupport` somewhere in your code. Try removing it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same exact issue. I was finally able to narrow it down to the root cause, which in my case turned out to be what @Dilip pointed out above.

Somehow, HypermediaSupport was getting enabled in my project when I include `springfox` dependencies, even though I didn't have the `@EnableHypermediaSupport` annotation explicitly in my project.  I think Spring was enabling it automagically because I had `@EnableAutoConfiguration` in my main java configuration class.

I was able to overcome this issue by excluding 'HypermediaAutoConfiguration' via the `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {HypermediaAutoConfiguration.class})` annotation in my java config class.

After I did this step, the exception went away. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is still on my list of "to-fix" but I think your solution is correct so I'm going to accept it. Will update if/when I get a chance to verify.

Comment: Update: this did indeed work perfectly. Cheers @stirfries

Comment: I have same problem, can we trace what really enables HypermediaAutoConfiguration?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your converts like example below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL)
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

        @Override
        protected void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
                converters.add(converter());
                addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(converters);
        }

        @Bean
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter() {
                return new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(new JacksonObjectMapper().getObjectMapper());
        }

}
```

*JacksonObjectMapper is my mapper class.