# Are there any Spring Boot documentation for understanding how web mvc configuration is work?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I find out solution for Jackson customization ([Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder enable field visibility ANY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29807879/jackson2objectmapperbuilder-enable-field-visibility-any#35326628)) by trial-and-error method.

And there are some question about it:

- Why doesn't it works until I remove `@EnableWebMvc`?
- Why `@Bean` doesn't work if I put it to `@Configuration` class extended from `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`?

I put breakpoint to main `ObjectMapper, MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` constructors and found in simple spring boot web mvc application

`ObjectMapper` created 9 times!

`MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` created 8 times!

Why? and why no ambiguous during `@Autowired` for `ObjectMapper`?

All this question could be express in single one: are there any docs to get known how all of this configuration works together?

Comment: If you add `@EnableWebMvc` you disable auto configuration from spring boot because it already detects your own configuration. If you add it as a bean it overrides again the default. When doing it like you do, you basically have a `BeanPostProcessor` which further modifies the bean created somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

> Why doesn't it works until I remove `@EnableWebMvc`

When you use `@EnableWebMvc` you are telling Spring Boot that you want to take complete control of configuring Spring MVC. This is covered in the [Spring Boot reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-switch-off-default-mvc-configuration) where it says "the easiest way to take complete control over MVC configuration is to provide your own `@Configuration` with the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation. This will leave all MVC configuration in your hands."

> I put breakpoint to main ObjectMapper, MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter constructors and found in simple spring boot web mvc application
>
> ObjectMapper created 9 times!
>
> MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter created 8 times!
>
> Why?

A number of default `ObjectMapper` and `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` instances are created by Spring MVC (and others). The default instances are then customised or replaced by Spring Boot as required.

> And why no ambiguous during @Autowired for ObjectMapper?

Autowiring only cares about instances of a class that are Spring beans. If an instance has been created and has not be exposed as a Spring bean autowiring will know nothing about it.

> All this question could be express in single one: are there any docs to get known how all of this configuration works together?

The [Spring Boot reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) covers a lot of this. In addition to the section on `@EnableWebMvc` linked to above, [the appendix that lists all of the auto-configuration classes](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#auto-configuration-classes) may also be of interest. Lastly, for understanding how things like `@Autowired` work, I would recommend reading the [Spring Framework reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/).

Comment: Andy, thank you for detail answer and documents reference.
I'd like to have some document similar to picture of "spring container bean lifecycle" (http://piyushramani8.blogspot.ru/2013/07/spring-container-bean-life-cycle.html) if it is possible, to have a look from top.

Curious, but jackson serialized fields only when I REMOVE `@EnableWebMvc` above 

       `@Configuration
       public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`.

But work OK with or without it in my own `@Configuration` class.
What is the difference in what class I annotated by `@EnableWebMvc`?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [`WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java)