# Register JavaTimeModule with the default objectmapper in springboot

Tags: java, java-time, objectmapper, jackson2

I define a `JavaTimeModule`:

```
@Bean public Module java8TimeModule() {
    JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
    return javaTimeModule; 
}
```

However, it does not register itself with the default objectmapper. I am using jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar.

The online help of `JavaTimeModule()` in Eclipse IDE says that:

> Note that as of 2.6, this module does NOT support auto-registration.

Not sure if it is still the same case for jackson-databind-2.8.9 causing `JavaTimeModule` not registering with the default objectmapper.

I do not want to create a new objectmapper. As in the past when I tried this, I had another issue with the objectmapper I created.

Springboot doc says:

> Defining a @Bean of type Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder will allow you to customize both default ObjectMapper and XmlMapper.

But I could not find code examples and not sure how to do it.

If I define a `@Bean` of type `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`, will it replace the default one? What is the consequence of it? And how to get the default objectmapper from `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an existing link on how to customize the default objectMapper at [Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder enable field visibility ANY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29807879/jackson2objectmapperbuilder-enable-field-visibility-any).

I also found out the problem in my program. The JavaTimeModule is automatically registered with the default objectMapper with jackson-databind-2.8.9. The issue in my program is caused by using a newly created objectMapper. I should have used the default objectMapper by @Autowired objectMapper.